# How do I align a sidebar to the left of the main content area?

Tags: css, html

Hey all, so basically I have a very simple layout with a header image, a main centered text area. And a sidebar that is to the left of the main centered text area. 
This is basically how my layout looks:

```
<center>Header</center>
<div style="float:left;">Sidebar</div>
<center>Main Area</center>
```

Well the sidebar is obviously going to align all the way to the left side of the page, what I would like it to do is still be on the left side of the page, but I want it to "hug" the main centered area.

Here is a basic picture of what it looks like now, and an arrow of what I would like to happen:
http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/2307/exampleps.jpg

Comment: Avoid using the center element, it is deprecated. Also, you might find http://jsfiddle.net/ useful for sharing your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rRm7k/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header"> HEADER </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="sidebar"> SIDEBAR </div>
        <div id="main"> MAIN CONTENT </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { width:500px; margin:0 auto; }
#body { overflow:auto; }
#sidebar { float:left; width:150px; min-height:400px; }
```

Comment: nice, but id's like header body are confusing

Comment: @crl I’d make these changes if I were to implement this today: 1. semantic `<header>`, `<aside>`, `<main>` elements; 2. a Flexbox layout; 3. a mobile-first responsive layout using media queries (sidebar collapses above or below main content)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with all divs instead:

```
<div>Header</div>
<div style="float:left;width:250px">Sidebar</div>
<div style="float:right;">Main Area</div>
```

Comment: but i need the main area and header to be centered..
I do have the header and main area inside div's

Comment: Try centering the middle using sidebars left and right.  One can be empty. Or add an appropriately sized margin to the right of the main area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MwEun/1/

You have to fit the width of the elements to your needs but should work. This example is a really basic version of an really easy html layout.

A good  and rock solid solution for centering elements is to set a width (e.g. 500px) and then adding `margin: 0 auto;`